# Webpack export all components without redundancy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have following directory structure:

```
- modules/ |
           |--- a
                |---- p.jsx
                |---- a_directory/not_to_export.jsx
                |-----q.jsx
           |   
           |--- b
                |---- r.jsx
                |-----s.jsx
           |
           |--- c
                |---- t.jsx
```

A simple question to ask would be  - How do I export each module with their path in webpack for use in webbrowser.

Example: `require('a/p.jsx')` should return reference to the p module.

More elaborated goal:

- Each top-level jsx, should be treated as a module ex: `a/p.jsx`, `a/q.jsx`,`b/r.jsx`,`b/s.jsx`,`c/t.jsx`.
- All these modules should be actually be referenced using their paths like: in b/r.jsx, I want to access `a/p.jsx`.
- Everything compiled to a single jsx, basically require statement to be synchronous.
- if possible cached builds
- require should be exported, like outside of build, I should be able to load  a component, eg: `require("a/p.jsx")` can be usable outside of the build, instead of only export of entrypoint.

This behaviour is very similar to what brunch produces, the only problem is brunch doesn't support conditional require/import statements.

Answer (score 1):

> - Each top-level jsx, should be treated as a module ex: `a/p.jsx`, `a/q.jsx`, `b/r.jsx`, `b/s.jsx`, `c/t.jsx`.
> - All these modules should be actually be referenced using their paths like: in `b/r.jsx`, I want to access `a/p.jsx`.

To configure how wepack resolves absolute paths see the [resolve option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). You would have to add your modules folder to the resolver. So in your webpack config add:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'modules']
  }
};
```

I assumed that your `modules` folder is on the same level as your `node_modules` folder.

> - Everything compiled to a single `jsx`, basically require statement to be synchronous.
> - require exports.

To build for use with node js use the [target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) option:

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node'
};
```

Comment: Yes, that partially solves the problem of resolution. I think if combined with `NamedModulesPlugin()` it can lead to a better solution, instead of changing the resolver. 

If modules are exported by their path, we probably won't need to fix the resolver - I guess.

Comment: @MadhurendraSachan How does it only "partially" solve the problem? You wrote that you want the subfolders of `modules` to be importable by their path. You did not say you want to name them. So that is the solution you asked for. Of course if you want to name them there may be other (better) solutions. Also what do you mean with "exported by their path"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. 
`require should be exported, like outside of build, I should be able to load a component, eg: require("a/p.jsx") can be usable outside of the build, instead of only export of entrypoint.`, Also I am building it for web environment. Trying to use requirejs